# Regex: Get everything after the first occurrence of a space after a word

Tags: python, regex, splunk

I need to get all the characters after the first space after a string. 
E.g. I need to get `{'s':'2'}` from a string that is of format:

```
a=1 session=<value> {'s'='2'}
```

The value will be of random length without space and there will be space before `{'s'='2'}`. So `{'s'='2'}` will always occur after the string 'session=' and the first space after that and there will be variable number of key value pairs like `a=1` before `session`.

E.g.

```
From: a=1 b=2 session=sdasdsadsa {'foo':'2'}         # I need to get {'foo':'2'}
From: a=1 b=2  c=3 session=s2312dssdaa {'bar':'3'}   # I need to get {'bar':'3'}
```

Comment: The first space in that string is the one between `1` and `session`.

Comment: Why do you want to use the second space?

Comment: there will be multiple key value pairs before the session

Comment: Are you looking for the values after session=<value> or just any session=

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Could you be more specific/give more examples and what you've tried? Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: sorry about not being clear about this

Comment: Please clarify your question. What, exactly, are you asking for?

Answer (score 0):

Simple one liner:

```
print(string.split(substr)[1][1:])
```

Where `string` is your string and `substr` is the substring.

This breaks the string into lists then joins the second to last values with a space again.

Output:

```
>>> string = "a=1 session=<value> {'s'='2'}"
>>> substr = "session=<value>"
>>> print(string.split(substr)[1][1:])
{'s'='2'}
>>>
```

Comment: can you help me out in regex since i need to use this in splunk

Comment: This doesn't work if there are >1 key/value pairs before the string.

Answer (score 0):

This regexp should work `/^\S*\s+(\S+) /`

It is probably a better way of writing it. As this does quite many operations.

Comment: If you provided an explanation of what the various parts of the expression do, it would be helpful to the OP -- as well as to future site visitors who come across this page.